# Conditionally removing from array if last character is []

Tags: r

I'm trying to get all stock tickers/abbreviation from a page. But when I scrape the page, some unwanted tickers come along, basically they all end with `F` or `(space)` for example `"BDLL4F "` or `"QCOM34F"` . I managed to remove them using gsub() and regex.

```
stocktickers = c("PETR4", "VALE3", "MDNE3", "BDLL4F ", "QCOM34F", "SANB11", "USIM5")
stocktickers = gsub("(.*[ F]$)","NULL",stocktickers)
stocktickers = stocktickers[stocktickers!="NULL"] 

> stocktickers
[1] "PETR4"  "VALE3"  "MDNE3"  "SANB11" "USIM5"
```

Is there any function that would conditionally drop the string from the array if the value begins or ends with a specified character or integer?

Comment: if you're trying to parse html, you'll have better luck with the `rvest` package instead of regex. If you're onlu trying to sort out a regex matching question, consider simplifying your question to focus on that, with an example of input and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted tickers using regex.

For example, with `grep` :

```
stocktickers = c("PETR4", "VALE3", "MDNE3","BDLL4F ","QCOM34F", "SANB11","USIM5")
grep("(F|\\s)$",stocktickers, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "PETR4"  "VALE3"  "MDNE3"  "SANB11" "USIM5"
```

This removes the values from `stocktickers` where it ends either with `"F"` or whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `endsWith` in `base R`

```
stocktickers[!endsWith(trimws(stocktickers), "F")]
#[1] "PETR4"  "VALE3"  "MDNE3"  "SANB11" "USIM5"
```

#### data

```
stocktickers = c("PETR4", "VALE3", "MDNE3","BDLL4F ","QCOM34F", "SANB11","USIM5")
```